# Redirect user to its subdomain in ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a react website where I assign a subdomain to the user when they sign up according to the username they enter, let's say their username is `john`, then the subdomain will be `john.mydomain.com`.

I would like to know how to redirect a user to its subdomain after they signup. I have access to the user data immediately after signup, such as username.

Sign up code:

```
export const signup = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // sign up the user
    const { data } = await api.signUp(formData);
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data });
    toast.success("Signed Up successfully");
    history.push("/");
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: "ERROR", data: error?.response?.data });
    toast.error(error?.response?.data?.message);
  }
};
```

Thank You.

Comment: how do you maintain your auth state? Cookie? Jwt?

Comment: I am using JWT. When a user signs up, from the backend it returns a JWT token that contains name, username and email id of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the subdomain is on the same host you can use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) or fallback on location:

```
const url = `${window.location.protocol}//${data.username}.${window.location.hostname}`
if (window.history) {
  window.history.pushState(data, '', url) // data included to subdomain
} else {
  const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data)
  const encodedData = btoa(stringifiedData) // base64 encode
  window.location.href = `${url}?data=${encodedData}
}
```

And then on the subdomain:

```
let data
if (window.history) {
  data = window.history.state // Access the state passed when signing up
  // save to localstorage or something
} else {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  const encodedData = params.get('data')
  const decodedData = atob(encodedData) // base64 decode
  const originalData = JSON.parse(decodedData)
  // save to localstorage or something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I do this, then I don't have access to the local storage data from the subdomain, and because of that, when users redirect to a subdomain, they need to log in again. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: You can include the signup data when redirecting, and then access it in the subdomain. I'll update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

In a new sign up, your server can generate a one time random string, which can be returned to your front end.

Then when you get the random string, you can pass it to your next page

```
const { data } = await api.signUp(formData);
dispatch({ type: "AUTH", data });
toast.success("Signed Up successfully");
window.location.href = `yourpath?authkey=${data.onetimekey}`
```

On arrival to your new page, the new page should get the authkey, pass it to backend, to confirm it's authentication status, and send back the user data you need, before you save it to your store in the new domain page.

You need to generate a random string (to be saved to a database of sort), because you should not be passing any private information via the query string.

Comment: What I am doing now is when a user signs up, it returns an encoded token from the backend that contains the name, username and email id of the user. And then I pass that token to the subdomain like this: window.location.href = `yourpath?token=${token}` and after that, I decode that token on the subdomain and save the user data to redux state and local storage.

Comment: But the problem with this approach is when a user logs out from the subdomain, they need to log out from the main domain again. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: for more reference, please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762610/how-to-logout-the-user-from-main-domain-and-subdomain-in-reactjs?noredirect=1#comment130250737_73762610

Comment: If you are using JWT, then there's no easy way to do this, unless you create a logout page on your main domain, that redirects back to your subdomain. Meaning - User Click Logout -> Redirect to maindomain, delete localstorage -> Redirect back to subdomain. When you are redirecting to main domain, you can add parameters in your query string to let your main domain know where to return to.

Comment: As advised in my answer, passing any private info, including a JWT via query string, is **not safe** as any info pass through query string can be logged e.g. in your web server log file. If you have done Google Login before, you will notice that when they pass JWT, they do not use query string, they use `#`

Comment: Okay, so I'll generate a random string on the backend and then send it back to the frontend when a user signs up or logs in. One question Do I need to immediately save that key to the database before sending it to frontend?

Comment: And Do I need to remove that key from the backend when a user logs out and generate a new one everytime when a user logs in or signs up?

Comment: Yeah, it's a one time key, like a nonce. So you delete that key once you used it. You see this method used very often e.g. sending email links to reset password. It is the same logic.

Comment: If you want to pass the jwt through URL somewhow, you need to use `url/#{token}` instead of `url/$token={token}` and access it via `window.location.hash`. Not sure whether you can see the difference.